# Flutter state and Screen management via runApp()

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, state-management

I use `runApp()` to change all the screens in my flutter App, but I have the feeling it is bad practice since I never saw anyone do it (I just think its an easy and fast way to change screen or refresh the current screen from an widget in another class whithout using key for `setState()` function). I never noticed any performance flaws from doing so and it works fine.
Are there reasons to use something different like Navigator etc?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, you use `runApp()` to change the screens?

Comment: Say i have a Button to launch another screen i will put intoon Tap
 `onTap() {
runApp(
//stateless widget for example
)}`
So runApp will start the Screen and kill the current Screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that I never saw anyone do so. However if you read the [runApp description](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/runApp.html) they say:

> Calling runApp again will detach the previous root widget from the screen and attach the given widget in its place. The new widget tree is compared against the previous widget tree and any differences are applied to the underlying render tree, similar to what happens when a StatefulWidget rebuilds after calling State.setState.

As it is an intended use, and there is a tree comparaison, I would assume that it is efficient.

**The advantage of Navigator** is that you can use named route, animate between screen, have a stack. If you don't need that, runApp is perfect.